# Flex big data volume performance (ADEP/LCDS dataservice)

Tags: performance, apache-flex, arraycollection, lcds

As we have found a solution for Hibernate, server side loads the data very fast : less than a sec for thousands of records and more. Now the problem is on transporting data from server to browser. Two issue:

1.The datagrid always waits until the ArrayCollection is fully loaded. We overcame this by specifying :

```
<destination id="someAssemble">
    <properties>
        <use-transactions>true</use-transactions>
        <source>com.assembler.SomeAssembler</source>
        <scope>application</scope>
        <item-class>vo.SomeVo</item-class>
        <network>
            <paging enabled="true" pageSize="50" />
        </network>
```

==> the datagrid started display quickly. The problem is the server stops loading data from row 51. Is there a way to force Flex keep loading the data in the background (by config or by code )

2.If I try to load a big ArrayCollection (for example more than 20K records), it locks down the whole browser. Is it possible to load it smoothly behind the scene?

Please help! Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the load problem is Flex?  Or is it the issue the transfer time between client and server?  I'm working on an app that can load 100K records into an AdvancedDataGrid in a minute. [I wouldn't call 1 minute fast, but considering the amount of records it was deemed acceptable].  I thought there was some way to have Flex communicate w/ LifeCycle in order to perform the paging automatically as the user scrolls through the Grid; but such is beyond my personal experience.

Comment: Why would you want to load 20k records into the client? Nobody is ever going to scroll through that much information. Just provide some good search functions and download only data that is relevant to the user.

Comment: @RIAstar : We have to load 20K because it is the data for the working session on which we need to loop through and get kinda sum, average,..etc.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com : I love lazy and paging from ADEP/lcds, it works great. But in our case, we have to loop through 20K records. And there will be ItemPendingError everywhere...

Comment: Can you calculate the sum/average on the server and just send that data back to Flex?  Depending on the data source, this sounds like something that SQL would excel at.

Comment: I must agree with Flextras. Such heavy calculations are better left to the server. Especially since ActionScript is single-threaded: such a loop might lock up your UI for a while.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am sorry for disappearing, I was too busy lately... I need an approach like "streaming" data : receive 100 first items to display (user happy to see something) then load the 900 items in the background (just like streaming video on youtube) ? Because the client ask us to load all the data, sooner or later of the session. Is that possible.